# How is a user supposed to find the latest Version of VMWare tools on the (My)Vmware website?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I am really curios how a user is supposed to find the latest version of the VMWare tools when entering the http://my.vmware.com/ website. Actually, I only find it externally when I google it. But what is the workflow, or flow of clicks a user is expected to follow when he wants to find it directly on the website? I cannot find it in the "VMWare Workstation ->Drivers and tools section", nor anywhere else on the website.

To be honest, I have never ever seen a product website which is so confusing to browse and to get information from than the VMware website, and I feel really sorry to say that.

Can anybody please give me a hint how a user can easily, reproducably always find the latest version of VMWare tools on the vmware webiste? Which steps are required? I simply cannot figure out myself.

Google of course directs me to https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/details?productId=742&downloadGroup=VMTOOLS1035 - I am looking for a way to find it without google, simply using what VMWare provides...

When I search VMWare Tools, I get the following results, which is not helpful:
[image: VMWare Tools Search]

Comment: There usually shouldn't be a reason to download VMware Tools manually for VMware Workstation.  The Tools are tied to the Workstation version; if you downloaded the full Workstation installer, it will come with the Tools.  If you downloaded a lite installer, it will download the corresponding Tools version on demand.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody please give me a hint how a user can easily, reproducibly always find the latest version of VMWare tools on the VMware website?

I was able to find the VMWare Tools without a problem by simply searching for it.

[image]

> I cannot find it in the "VMWare Workstation ->Drivers and tools section", nor anywhere else on the website.

You cannot find it linked to VMWare Workstation because it is linked to VMWare vSphere.

> Which steps are required?

There are no steps.  It only took a minute to determine that VMWare Tools was linked to VMWare vSphere.

[image]

[image]

You can also search for a specific version of VMWare Tools.

[image]